# Is localstorage data encryption necessary?

Tags: javascript, storage, local, cart

I am making an add to cart system first time
and instead of using php , I am using javascript i.e in client side.

**will it be safe ??** 
or if it is not, then what should I do to secure the data in localstorge?

Comment: localstorage _can_ be safe, but it really depends. You should try to explain what you are worried about? Someone else modifying the data, a user modifying their own data?

Comment: What kind of info are you planning on putting in there? If it's just quantities of items selected that's fine, but certainly don't _trust_ any information in local storage since the user can freely edit it. So calculate prices and do other validatoins on the backend

Comment: In short, what are you trying to protect/prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it might be, in your case. As users might be able to manipulate the cost or quantity of item from local storage.

And now if you use such tampered data in checkout sessions, you might face issues regarding collection of payments.

My recommendation would be storing only authentication cookies in local storage but no app data.

For that, as a very easy and fast solution, go for something like Firestore